# What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: android

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> Error:Execution failed for task > ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > >    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:    java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: >    com/android/volley/Request$Priority.class

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.the.ex"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

   /* compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'*/
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    compile project(':payUMoneysdk')

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I think that your sub-project `payUMoneysdk` already uses volley, and you add it to your main project again. You should'n do that.

Answer (score 0):

Add these inside Android{} body :

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
```